# SQL: Update Subquery For Each Row in Main Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a list of football results in one table, each row is a match and contains all data from that match i.e. Home(team), HomeGoals, AwayGoals, Away(team), I want to cycle through each match, get the home team, check their last 6 matches and display only the matches where the specified team scored 4 goals or more in at least one of their last 6 matches.

I have the following code which creates a table, partitions by team name and numbers every row based on the date of their game, then runs through the table again and displays only the games that meet the criteria specified above.

The problem is I need the 'Last6' table to update itself based on the date of the game being referenced in the main query, so that I get the last 6 games from that date. At the moment it's just getting the last 6 games from the very last game in the table.

```
WITH Last6
AS (
  SELECT Home
    ,HomeGoals
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Home ORDER BY Goals.DATE DESC
      ) GameNumber
  FROM Goals
  )
SELECT *
FROM Goals G
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM Last6
    WHERE G.Home = Last6.Home
      AND GameNumber <= 6
      AND HomeGoals >= 4
    )
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can find some tricks here:http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: You should tag what RDBMS you are using in your question.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012.